# Java Arrays.binarySearch with compareTo

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, object

I need to use Arrays.binarySearch on an array of custom objects. Here is the object:

```
class Range implements Comparable<Range>{

public int bottom;
public int top;

public Range(int botIn, int topIn) {
    this.bottom = botIn;
    this.top = topIn;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Range compareRange) {
    int compareQuantity = ((Range) compareRange).bottom; 
    return this.bottom - compareQuantity;
}}
```

In my main I first call `Arrays.sort(lowerBounds);` where lowerBounds is an array of Range elements. This works just fine and sorts them using the compareTo I wrote. Then I call `Arrays.binarySearch(lowerBounds, 0)` but I get "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to compareToTest.Range".

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Edit: here is main:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] A = {1, 5, 2, 1, 4, 0};
    // write your code in Java SE 6

    Range[] lowerBounds = new Range[A.length];
    for(int i=0; i< A.length; i++)
    {
        lowerBounds[i] = new Range(i-A[i], i+A[i]);
    }

    Arrays.sort(lowerBounds);

    for(int i=0; i< A.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(lowerBounds[i].bottom);  
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(lowerBounds, 0));   
}
```

Comment: Where is the `main()`-code? But my guess would be to try `Arrays.binarySearch(lowerBounds, new Range(0,0));` as the key object (the second parameter) has to be the same type as the array you pass in.

Comment: The second parameter of `binarySearch` is the value to search for, so it should not be an int but a `Range` object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Arrays.binarySearch` accepts two parameters - an array to search in, and the object you're looking for. You have supplied an array of `Range` object and an `int` (which is autoboxed to an `Integer`). Naturally, you can't search for an `Integer` in an array of `Range`s.

Instead, you should create the `Range` object you're looking for. E.g.:

```
Range r = new Range (0, 0);
Arrays.binarySearch (lowerBounds, r);
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays.binarySearch(lowerBounds, 0) is wrong because you are comparing Range Objects.SO you need to pass a Range Object instead of an Integer Object which results in java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to compareToTest.Range"

You need to create a RangeObject and pass it in binarySearch method

```
Range r = new Range(0,<any integer>)
Arrays.binarySearch (lowerBounds, r);
```